# Conseguir el ultimo elmento por fecha en mongoDB

Tags: base-de-datos, mongodb, sql

Tengo una colección que almacena documentos con siguiente estructura

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a82853464934e0ced4dcb"), "id_process" : 2, "fecha_termina" : "12/03/2020 01:42:12" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a82803464932c4838b3fb"), "id_process" : 2, "fecha_termina" : "12/03/2020 01:42:07" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a825e34649336ac628ba8"), "id_process" : 1, "fecha_termina" : "12/03/2020 01:41:33" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a82593464934884a59263"), "id_process" : 1, "fecha_termina" : "12/03/2020 01:41:28" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e6a81b93464935cf41d3455"), "id_process" : 1, "fecha_termina" : "12/03/2020 01:38:47" }
```

Ya que el id_proceso se puede repetir varias veces como podria traer solo los id_proceso que tenga la fecha mas reciente, agradezco su colaboracion ya que me encuentro un poco enrredado con la cosulta.

Lo estoy intentando de la siguiente manera pero me genera un error

```
db.log.distinct("id_process",{}).sort({"fecha_termina":-1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero que todo, en mongo la función `distinct` y `sort` no son dependientes, así que juntarlos no te servirá de mucho. para eso usa `aggregate` y le das los valores que necesitas de acuerdo a las condiciones. puedes ver con más detalles en esta [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bt1FeAN8za8)

donde encontrarás esta consulta:

```
  db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      "_id": "$id_process",
      "fecha_termina": {
        "$first": "$fecha_termina"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "_id": 0,
      id_process: "$_id",
      fecha_termina: "$fecha_termina"
    }
  }
])
```

lo primero le dices a mongo es que agrupe los elementos de esa colección, buscando los Objetos de Ids con el identificador `id_process` y además  identificador `first` donde muestre el registro con la nueva fecha registrada, después le agregas los valores al identificador `project` para que te visualice como tu desees. Si le cambias por el identificador `last`, verás que te trae los antiguos registros con esos `id_process`.
Espero te sirva.